# Drawing a line in time domain

Tags: algorithm

I am designing hardware which should gradually increase value of the variable from one value to another within specific range of clock cycles - graphically you can view it as drawing continuous line.

I used Bresenham's algorithm, but discovered that if time is less than variable value range, this algorithm is not applicable simply because clock cycle axis can not be physically swapped with variable's value axis - time is always contiguous.

I am looking for advice

- can Bresenham's be somehow modified to work in the abovementioned situation in octant 2 when axes can not be swapped;
- what other algorithm can be used for situations when x-range is less than y-range;
- maybe there's some other approach to the resolution and another algorithm covering both scenarios?

Limitations: division is not allowed, as well as FP-emulation. Multiplication is allowed (as well as addition and subtraction).

Update: modulo by number other than 2^n is not allowed. Only integer math (unsigned and/or signed). Algorithm setup should take one or two cycles.

Comment: Drawing lines always happens in a pixel domain. So there shouldn't be (can't be) any problems using Bresenham.

Comment: @HenkHolterman x-axis is time and can not be swapped with y-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bresenham's algorithm is easily adapted for this situation.

If the y range (`dy`) is greater than the x range (`dx`), then you can divide `dy/dx` into fractional and itegral parts:

- Use Bresenham's algorithm to calculate a line from `(x,y)` to `(x+dx,y+dy%dx)`
- Add `(x-dx)*floor(dy/dx)`, i.e. accumulate an extra `floor(dy/dx)` on every `x` increment.

Comment: Division is not allowed. Modulo is not allowed. Variables (registers) are only integer type.

Comment: @Anonymous you only have to do the division+modulus at setup time, and then store the results.  If your processor doesn't have a division instruction, then you can calculate it using the shift+subtract algorithm.  Maybe not fast enough to do on every x value, but probably fast enough to do at setup time

Comment: You coined the issue. Setup operation should completed within one or two clock cycles. Shift-subtract is division which is not allowed.

Comment: You're going to need to use some freedom that you haven't yet allowed:  limit choices for dx, push the division off onto the specifier, do it incrementally over several cycles, etc...